# Change date number to another language/script?

Tags: theme-development, functions, date-time

I previously was able to change the numbers of the date and time (into a number and date system of another language, like Khmer) for each post using a script like this in my functions.php:

```
function KhmerNumDate ($text) {
$text = str_replace('1', '១', $text);
$text = str_replace('2', '២', $text);
$text = str_replace('3', '៣', $text);
$text = str_replace('4', '៤', $text);
$text = str_replace('5', '៥', $text);
$text = str_replace('6', '៦', $text);
$text = str_replace('7', '៧', $text);
$text = str_replace('8', '៨', $text);
$text = str_replace('9', '៩', $text);
$text = str_replace('0', '០', $text); 
return $text;
}


add_filter('date', 'KhmerNumDate');
add_filter('the_date', 'KhmerNumDate');
add_filter('the_time', 'KhmerNumDate');
```

But now it is not working - is my code good? Would the code differ based on which theme I am using (I am currently using a modified child theme of Twenty-Twelve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because of the way the theme Twenty Twelve works (in their effort to make translation easy...).

The date for posts in Twenty Twelve is prepared by a function in functions.php called `twentytwelve_entry_meta()`

So to replace/translate the numbers in the date, I look for the line with `$date=` in the `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function (or preferably replicate the `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function in a child functions.php as I did):

```
$date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time></a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() )

    );

    //my added code - the_curlang() is used with the xili-language plugin, it returns the current language of the page

$languagedate = the_curlang();

if ( $languagedate == 'km_kh' ) {
$date = str_replace('1', '១', $date);
$date = str_replace('2', '២', $date);
$date = str_replace('3', '៣', $date);
$date = str_replace('4', '៤', $date);
$date = str_replace('5', '៥', $date);
$date = str_replace('6', '៦', $date);
$date = str_replace('7', '៧', $date);
$date = str_replace('8', '៨', $date);
$date = str_replace('9', '៩', $date);
$date = str_replace('0', '០', $date); 
}
```

Then everything looks great!

I'm not much of a programmer, so my code might not be the best option, but at least it works.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this way:

Change date, the_date, the_time to get_date, get_the_date,    get_the_time.

```
function KhmerNumDate ($text) {
    $text = str_replace('1', '១', $text);
    $text = str_replace('2', '២', $text);
    $text = str_replace('3', '៣', $text);
    $text = str_replace('4', '៤', $text);
    $text = str_replace('5', '៥', $text);
    $text = str_replace('6', '៦', $text);
    $text = str_replace('7', '៧', $text);
    $text = str_replace('8', '៨', $text);
    $text = str_replace('9', '៩', $text);
    $text = str_replace('0', '០', $text); 
    return $text;
    }


add_filter('get_date', 'KhmerNumDate');
add_filter('get_the_date', 'KhmerNumDate');
add_filter('get_the_time', 'KhmerNumDate');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest using a Wordpress built-in function for your specific need which is [`date_i18n($date_format, $time, $gmt)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n). Just pass the [php `date()` format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and the `timestamp` and Wordpress will display the date in your language (Language defined in `wp-config.php`).

Example from the codex page:

```
echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format') ,strtotime("11/15-1976"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for those languages that do not use roman numbers (1 2 3...) it will not change http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Date_and_Time_Locale_Settings. So to change the numbering system, you have to use a script (to my knowledge). But you are right for month names - I have modified my question to show that (because actually month names and day names can just be translated in the .po files of the theme).

Comment: There is also a Wordpress function that convert numbers into local format: `number_format_i18n($number)`, there is no codex reference for this function, but it should return the `number` in the localized format of the blog.